# Jquery + PHP, wrapped in Phonegap, how to keep users logged in?

Tags: php, jquery, session, mobile

I'm making a simple mobile web app where users should be able to login/authenticate to sign up for private events.
I love the way JQuery mobile looks and feels, but want PHP to do everything in the backend: Handle form processing, talk to the DB and so on.

I currently have no authentication, but want to add that.
Wrapping the current solution in Phonegap actually worked, but I suspect the authentication/session handling is going to crash with that.

My hope is that I can exchange data with a PHP script when:
- the form loads (to check for PHP user session etc), and
- a "submit" button is clicked.

I covered the submit button part, and it works. Data is sent to, and returned from my PHP processing script to the JQuery front-end.
For handling the submit event, for some reason this code worked:
*$(document).ready(function(){*
as opposed to an onclick thing which didn't work.

This baffles me, as I read that document.ready is an event that occurs when the document has completed loading.

Q1: Could this have something to do with me using Jquery mobile *sections* (

Q2: What would be the correct JQuery event/trigger to use prior to loading, to control form "context"? (based on data from backend PHP).

Q3a: Is it a viable solution to rely on PHP sessions in such a case?

Q4: Also considering that I'd like to Phonegap it...will a PHP session be able to "see" the Jquery-based, phonegap-wrapped app like a client session just like if it was someone using a web-browser?
4b. When does a Phonegap app user session "end"? (When does the user have to log in again...).

I know similar questions have been raised several times, but please consider I'm a gullible idiot that knows too little to understand which case is similar enough to mine. There are some concepts here that I need to grasp before I can decide what to investigate and ask about :-)

Here's to tolerance and understanding! Cheers!
Eivind

Comment: You can store mobile id and users id in database with flag logged_in when they first logged in. Then again if user open that app, you can check the mobile id with the record in database whether user is exists or not and if exists then whats his/her status.

Answer (score 1):

You can store mobile id and users id in database with flag logged_in when they first logged in. Then again if user open that app, you can check the mobile id with the record in database whether user is exists or not and if exists then whats his/her status.